# How can I overcome long compile times caused by a large amount of generated code?

Tags: c++, perl, opengl, header, mingw

I have been looking around for other [OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) file loaders and I found
[obj2opengl](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/) by Heiko Behrens.

I like how simple this converter is, but there's only one problem. When compiling, it takes a really long time to build because that converted file is 63 MB when converted.

Is there a way to maybe skip the checking of a header file? If not, then is there probably a way to make my project compile faster without removing the header file?

If any code is needed, comment and I will respond ASAP.

My IDE is [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), with MinGW as the compiler on Windows 32-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this script probably does is converting a OBJ file into a series of OpenGL commands. **That's really not how one should use OpenGL.**

What you actually should do is either implement yourself, or get some library that dynamically loads a OBJ file at your programs runtime. Given the fact that Lightwave OBJ file are really simple to parse this should be a nice exercise.

Comment: alright thanks for the answer, i guess ill look up some examples and try parsing my model by myself. also im not sure if i asked this, but im still wondering why my glm object is not applying the texture.. is there a way to change the model(the GLMmodel)'s texture by myself? instead of using its default texture loading?